Satisfying many congruences with few points
Recently, I posted another question on the following problem:

For a given positive integer $S$, consider the following set of conditions:
$$\bigcup_{AB = S}\bigcup_{i = 0...A-1\\j = 0...B-1}\begin{cases} x = i\mod A\\y = j\mod B \end{cases}$$
Is there a set of $O(S)$ points $(x, y)$ such that every condition is satisfied by at least one point?


Essentially, we want to color $O(S)$ cells of an infinite grid, so that when "wrapping" the grid into a rectangle of area $S$, it always ends up fully colored. Below is an example for $S=4$.


It turns out that every condition can be satisfied with just $S$ points. I am now interested in some modifications of this problem:

Is it still possible if we consider all $AB \leq S$ instead of $AB = S$?
Is it still possible if the points have to form a single connected component? Here, consider points $(x, y)$ and $(x', y')$ adjacent if $\max(|x - x'|, |y - y'|) = 1$.
Both conditions?

I want to prove that it is impossible at least in one of these cases (although I am not even sure if this is true). I know it is impossible with both conditions with just $S$ points. The closest I've got to disproving the existence of an $O(S)$ solution is the following argument:

Suppose that for any $S$ there is a solution that uses at most $MS$ points. We can choose $M$ so that this upper bound is reached infinitely often. We can pick a large $S$, such that exactly $M(S-1)$ points are needed to satisfy all conditions for $AB \leq S - 1$. Then we will have only $M$ points to add to satisfy all remaining conditions for $AB = S$. This seems quite unlikely to be possible for $S$ much larger $M$.

We can also make sure that $S$ in the argument above has many divisors. I've made some other observations but nothing seems to work. Of course, I also tried to find a linear solution with no success. I've been stuck on this problem for quite a while now. Do you have any idea how it can be solved?

The solution on the other thread only applies when $S$ has only one prime divisor.
